# Image staying visible on canvas despite being toggled as hidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating a game for school. I have most of the game working minus the shop. However, the first time you "kill" the enemy by clicking the attack button a few times he will respawn all normally and come back onto the screen, but the second you kill him his "idle" frame stays visible while the death animation is playing. I have looked through my code a lot and I can't figure out why at all. The game code is too big to copy into here but here is the part that does it. Essentially, you click attack and once the life count gets to 0 it runs the death animation and gets a new life value based off of the stuff you've bought in the store.

```
def coinUp():
    global coins
    global coinsCounter
    coins = coins + coinIncrease
    fightScreen.delete(coinsCounter)
    coinsCounter = fightScreen.create_text(210, 30, text = coins, font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("gold"))

def enemyHealth():
    global healthCounter
    global eneLives
    eneLives = eneLives - attackPower
    if eneLives >= 1:
        fightScreen.delete(healthCounter)
        healthCounter = fightScreen.create_text(595, 30, text = eneLives, font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("red"))
    elif eneLives <= 0:
        fightScreen.delete(healthCounter)
        fightScreen.itemconfig(enemyIdle, state = HIDDEN)
        enemyDie()
        time.sleep(2)
        enemyWalk()

def eneHealthDecider():
        global healthCounter
        global eneLives
        eneLives = coinIncrease*attackPower
        if eneLives % 2 != 0:
            eneLives = eneLives + 1
        healthCounter = fightScreen.create_text(595, 30, text = eneLives, font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("red"))

coinsText = fightScreen.create_text(100, 30, text = "Coins:", font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("gold"))
coinsCounter = fightScreen.create_text(210, 30, text = coins, font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("gold"))
healthCounter = fightScreen.create_text(595, 30, text = eneLives, font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("red"))
healthText = fightScreen.create_text(470, 30, text = "Health:", font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("red"))    
attack = fightScreen.create_window(170, 380, window = Button(fightScreen, text = "Attack!", font = ("calibri" , 20), command = shoot))
openShop = fightScreen.create_window(80, 380, window = Button(fightScreen, text = "Shop", font = ("calibri" , 20), command = shop))

mainloop()
```

Comment: The way we debug code is to run it and see whatis happening, sometimes inserting print statements etc. To do this we need code that runs except for the most obvoius cases. Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's very hard.

Comment: I wish I could attach a .zip file that would include the file and all the images. What makes no sense whatsoever is that the exact same code is running twice with different results.

Comment: Well, something is not exactly the same or it would behave the same. Still; it's almost impossible to debug a code you can't run :(